# Data Extension 101

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Been trying (without success) to insert a row of custom data into an email triggered out of SFDC that picks up a DE from Exact Target.

Read lots and lots of documentation and tested many hours but no dice.

Could it look like this: %%=Lookup("303030","PURL","Subscriber Key",Subscriber Key)=%%

Where 303030 equals the external key of the non-sendable data extension
PURL is the field I want to display
Subscriber Key is the loaded primary piece of data in the DE
Subscriber Key is coming over from the SFDC ET plug-in

Is there more?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. You need to use the name, not the key, for the first parameter.
2. That last argument is going to need to be altered.  If its custom, [Subscriber Key] may work.  Otherwise, the internal string for subscriber key is _subscriberkey (see http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/).

Hope this helps.